# AverageIF won't calculate correctly if I select the whole column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

In Excel, AverageIf miscalculates the data I want when I use the range `B:B` instead of `B2:B21`, even though nothing else follows B21 (the column is empty after that).

The average when I use `B:B` as the range(not the sum range) is `747`, but it is `902` when I use the specific range `B2:B21`. All other parts of the formula are the same.

```
=AVERAGEIF(B:B,"NY",D2:D21)
```

versus

```
=AVERAGEIF(B2:B21,"NY", D2:D21)
```

The purpose is to calculate average sales for New York salespersons.

Comment: That should be `=AVERAGEIF(B:B,"NY",D:D)`.

Comment: Please check the following link and then update your question: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to not get false positives all ranges should be the same size and shape:

```
=AVERAGEIF(B:B,"NY",D:D)
```

With your formula it is comparing B1 but returning D2 so the results will be one row off.

It is the same as doing:

```
=AVERAGEIF(B1:B20,"NY", D2:D21)
```

So if `B2` = `NY` the formula will use `D3` not `D2` in the output.